# Enable MathJax for formatting mathematical formulas?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

This question directly relates to the previous Meta-PSE question, [Can we have MathJax please to format mathematical formulas?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4770/11924)

I've made this a separate question, because it's unclear how much of a "consensus" the previous question garnered. As of this posting (2021-04-30), the previous question had 9 upvotes in favor of enabling MathJax, and 1 downvote against. But the question was asked in June 2015. Until about early 2019, popular Meta-PSE questions could expect roughly 15–20 net votes. So a nearly 6-year-old feature request having a mere 8 net upvotes (out of 10 total) doesn't seem like a very strong consensus.

Personally, I'm a strong proponent of enabling MathJax for the site. I think the benefits of having a convenient way of creating standard LaTeX-formatted math formulas outweighs the potential negatives of having MathJax enabled (primarily, reportedly slower site load time).

Please don't suggest things such as some sort of delayed determination of whether to load MathJax based on whether the question or any answers have MathJax content. That is a non-starter: enabling MathJax is a per–Stack Exchange site determination, all-or-nothing. There is no ability to custom-code the loading of this feature for Photography Stack Exchange. Also note that once MathJax is enabled, it's a one-way thing; once questions or answers contain LaTeX content, they won't display correctly if MathJax is disabled.

Please vote on the yes/no answers below to indicate your preference. Please also add additional answers if you have concerns or issues that haven't been addressed in this question or in the previous [Meta-PSE MathJax question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4770/11924)

Comment: Just closing this as a duplicate since all the discussion's on the other post, which is the one that got escalated to us and where we've now responded.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes – we should enable MathJax

The benefits of LaTeX formatting will make it easier to produce clear and well-formatted mathematical formulas. This will make the questions and answers that take advantage of LaTeX formatting appear more professional, and make our content easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

### No – we should not enable MathJax

The purported benefits of enabling MathJax do not outweigh the drawback of the heavy dependency of page load time (as much as [0.3–0.4 seconds on Stackoverflow in 2013](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/1123413)).

People wishing to format formulas can use services such as [Codecogs.com](https://editor.codecogs.com) to create LaTeX-generated equations as PNGs and upload them to their posts.

Comment: I have used the Codecogs tool [several](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/122305/11924) [times](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/75692/11924) in the past. It's _a_ solution, but I don't think it's a _good_ solution.